# TypeScript Server Error using coc-tsserver

Tags: javascript, typescript, neovim, neovim-plugin, tsserver

I have a problem with the coc-tsserver installed on Neovim, if I open a js or ts file in a directory without node_modules it works correctly, but if I open a file whose directory has node_modules I have this error:

```
[coc.nvim]: UnhandledRejection: Error: <semantic> TypeScript Server Error ([object Object])       
The "interval" argument must be of type number. Received undefined
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "interval" argument must be of type number. Received undefined
```

I tried reinstall CoC and coc-tsserver but doesn't worked for me.